# Google API javascript

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am doing a custom google map with API

I put the URL link :

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green|label:G|40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red|label:C|40.718217,-73.998284&key=AIzaSyCTFUKmdIRSSod5v1oqhIXJOmkOPMsdFp0

I received this error:

> The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/static_maps_backend?project=_

I enabled API AND THE error still exist 
Can you please help me find the solituion for my problem

Comment: I solve the problem , the solution was that i should put the API enabled in the API credentials section But i dnt want the map to be just an image , how can it be a real map?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Google maps api your going to have to first off enable the maps api in the Google developer console for that project.   Then you will need to enable billing for the project as there is no longer a free tear for maps api.

Once you have done that you can create an api key and use it in your code.

> The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/static_maps_backend?project=_

This message means that you have not enabled the maps api for your project.  It can take a few minutes before it kicks in if you just enabled it.  Make sure you have done it for the cogrect project as well by clicking on the link that it showed you.

Comment: i enabled the map api few days ago

Comment: I have seen it a number of times where it was on the wrong project or the wrong api.   Check again.   Google is giving you that error for a reason.

Comment: i enabled :Geocoding ,Geolocation ,Maps JavaScript ,Maps Static API

Answer (score -1):

You are going to need maps javascript API for a real map and embed it in a div

Here is a basic example on how to achieve that.

In the script tag in the html section you need to replace YOUR_API_KEY for the real one from google.

```
jsbin example
https://jsbin.com/xiragigegi/edit?html,css,js,output
```